# How do I sort a 2D array to ascending order?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array like this:

```
[0] [4]
[1] [3]
[0] [7]
[7] [8]
[1] [2]
[7] [3]
```

And I want something like this:

```
[0] [4]
[0] [7]
[1] [2]
[1] [3]
[7] [3]
[7] [8]
```

Comment: Can you edit your post please? It is unclear what the layout of your 2D array is. Also, try to explain your question in more detail.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, this community  is not a *coding service for free*. Please show your actual attempts trying to solve the task and address a specific issue and surely someone will take care of giving an aswer soon

Comment: like first all the even entrys then the odd?

Comment: if yes your last entrys in what you are want are switched

Answer (score 1):

This will get the array `a` and sort it by column `0`. If cumlumn `0` have equal numbers it will look at column `1` to do the sorting.

```java
int[][] a = {{0, 4}, {1, 3}, {0, 7}, {7, 8}, {1, 2}, {7, 3}};

for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    if (a[i][0] > a[i + 1][0]) {
        int[][] temp = {{a[i + 1][0], a[i + 1][1]}};
        a[i + 1][0] = a[i][0];
        a[i + 1][1] = a[i][1];
        a[i][0] = temp[0][0];
        a[i][1] = temp[0][1];
        i = 0;
    } else if (a[i][0] == a[i + 1][0]) {
        if (a[i][1] > a[i + 1][1]) {
            int[][] temp = {{a[i + 1][0], a[i + 1][1]}};
            a[i + 1][0] = a[i][0];
            a[i + 1][1] = a[i][1];
            a[i][0] = temp[0][0];
            a[i][1] = temp[0][1];
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, if you replace your swaps with `int[] temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[i+1]; a[i+1] = temp;` it is a little cleaner.  This just swaps the actual 1D arrays instead of making a new one. But in any event the original works so +1.

Answer (score 1):

Use a comparator to compare the first cell and then if equal, compare the second cell.  When streaming a `2D` array, the result is a stream of `1D` arrays (in this case of length 2).  Then they are sorted using the comparator, and then returned as a `2D` array.

```java
int[][] array = {{0, 4}, {1, 3}, {0, 7}, {7, 8}, {1, 2}, {7, 3}};

Comparator<int[]> first = Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0]);
Comparator<int[]> second = Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[1]);
array = Arrays.stream(array)
        .sorted(first.thenComparing(second))
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

for (int[] a : array) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Prints

```
[0, 4]
[0, 7]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[7, 3]
[7, 8]
```

Here is a non-streams approach using a selection sort. Not very efficient for large data sets though.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int k = i + 1; k < array.length; k++) {
        // sort in ascending order on the first cells and then
        // if equal, on the second cells
        if (array[k][0] > array[i][0]
                || array[k][0] == array[i][0]
                && array[k][1] > array[i][1]) {

            // simply swap each 1D array
            int[] temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Or as [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) kindly suggested, using the above comparator. This does an in place sort without creating a new array.

```java
Arrays.sort(array, first.thenComparing(second));
```

Comment: Or to not create new array `Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt( (int[] row) -> row[0] ).thenComparingInt( (int[] row) -> row[1]) );`.